# Finding the Valid Date

Tags: python, function, datetime

I have a list of dates which are not valid (this can be a public holiday in certain area/country or any other non valid date and this can be a long list and include several years):

```
Holiday = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-09','2020-01-10']
```

I want to create a search function such that given certain date, the function will search the previous valid date (this will exclude weekend and Holiday). For example, the current date is '2020-01-13', then the valid date would be '2020-01-08' because '2020-01-09' and '2020-01-10' are in Holiday and '2020-01-11' and '2020-01-12' are weekend.

My function:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

def the_date(today):

    today = datetime.strptime(today,'%Y-%m-'%d').date()
    the_date = today - BDay(1)
    the_date = datetime.strftime(the_date,'%Y-%m-%d')

    if the_date in Holiday:
       the_new_date = (datetime.strptime(Holiday[Holiday.index(the_date)],'%Y-%m-%d') - BDay(1)).date()
       the_new_date = datetime.strftime(the_new_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    
    else:
       the_new_date = the_date
   
    return the_new_date
```

When I use this function:

```
today = '2020-01-13'


the_new_date = the_date(today)
```

surely the_new_date is '2020-01-09', because my function can't identify two consecutives non-valid day (Holiday)- Is there any way I can make my function to identify two consecutive Holiday so my result (the_new_date) will be '2020-01-08'? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.weekday()` from `datetime`, to write a recursive function `the_date`.
Additionally, scaled up the program by using the holidays module (https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) to dynamically retrieve holidays for given country (Here I chose Germany as this is your listed home country) So you no longer need to hardcode your `Holiday` list (unless you have specific company holidays or similar):

```
import holidays

from datetime import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

Holiday = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10']
Holiday = [datetime.strptime(holiday, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for holiday in Holiday]
ge_holidays = holidays.Germany()


def the_date(day):
    if (day - BDay(1)).date().weekday() in (5, 6):
        if (day - BDay(2)).date().weekday() in (5, 6):
            new_date = (day - BDay(3)).date()
        else:
            new_date = (day - BDay(2)).date()
    else:
        new_date = (day - BDay(1)).date()
    if new_date in Holiday or new_date in ge_holidays:
        return the_date(new_date)
    return new_date


# Test:
print(the_date(datetime.today()), '\n')

for day in Holiday:
    print(the_date(day))
```

Returning:

```
2020-07-10 

2019-12-31
2020-01-08
2020-01-08
```